# Sort array of objects using value from object of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

#### Edit: It appears I've overthought the problem and asked for a simple `Array.sort()` Thank you Nina Scholz!

I have an array of objects I want to sort by the value from another object who's values are arrays containing a `ts`. The array of objects I want sorted has an `id` reference to the object that contains the `ts` value to be sorted on, these arrays are sorted with the highest `ts` always in position `[0]`. Here's a few snippets of code to explain:

## Array of Objects to be sorted

```
[
  { id: 'abc' },
  { id: 'def' },
  { id: 'ghi' }
]
```

## Object of arrays containing timestamp

```
{
  abc: [{ ts: 6 }, { ts: 1 }],
  def: [{ ts: 4 }, { ts: 2 }],
  ghi: [{ ts: 5 }, { ts: 3 }]
}
```

## Expected sorted result

```
[
  { id: 'abc' },
  { id: 'ghi' },
  { id: 'def' }
]
```

Comment: what is the logic to sort?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you attach your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the value of the first item of the referenced object for sorting.

```js
var array = [{ id: 'abc' }, { id: 'def' }, { id: 'ghi' }],
    object = { abc: [{ ts: 1 }, { ts: 6 }], def: [{ ts: 4 }, { ts: 2 }], ghi: [{ ts: 3 }, { ts: 5 }] };
    
array.sort((a, b) => object[a.id][0].ts - object[b.id][0].ts);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed the answer was so simple. Thank you for reminding me to not overthink things!